# table view cells not showing Swift

Tags: swift

I'm making an app and suddenly my app does not show table view cells.
My tableView(QNATableView) looks like this,

[tableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxIma.png)

and if i turn on simulator, it doesn't show any cells like this [tableView in iOS simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1DE5.png)

and following is its code.

```
import UIKit
import Parse


class QNATableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var posts = [PFObject]()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let query = PFQuery(className: "posts")
        query.includeKeys(["author","caption","details"])
        query.limit = 20
        query.findObjectsInBackground{ (posts, error)
            in
            if posts != nil{
                self.posts = posts!
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func questionButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "questionSegue", sender: Any?.self)
    }
   

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return posts.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 1
    }

    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let post = posts[posts.count - indexPath.section - 1]
        
        
        let captions = post["caption"]
        let detailss = post["details"]
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QNATableViewCellID") as! QNATableViewCell
        
        cell.caption.text = (captions as! String)
        cell.details.text = (detailss as! String)

        return cell
    }
    


}
```

Comment: Have you checked that you have more than zero posts (posts.count > 0)?

Comment: @mahan yes it has 9 posts if i do print(posts.count)

Comment: @mahan I just tried to do print(posts.count) in the function numberOfSections, and it prints out three lines of zeros and one line of 9 (the # of posts i got)